# Sap problem on the top and shelf of an outside bar

Tags: tabletop

About a month ago I built and painted an outside bar. I used wood planks from Lowe’s for the top and shelf. I sanded, painted, and then used poly acrylic on the top and shelf.

Now the sap is coming through at the knots and changing the color of my paint.

What can I do to fix this problem without having to strip it back down to the wood?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix a new douglas fir tongue and groove exterior floor that is oozing sap?](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/4075/how-do-i-fix-a-new-douglas-fir-tongue-and-groove-exterior-floor-that-is-oozing-s)

Answer (score 1):

Dewaxed shellac is the traditional way of sealing knots, sap veins, ... and has worked for me Bulls Eye Clear Shellac is one of many brands, brush or in a spray can.

Comment: FYI, the traditional sealer for knots was plain shellac, not dewaxed. And worth noting that SealCoat specifies on the label that it's wax free where Bull's Eye does not, so it would appear you were recommending the genuine traditional way :-)

Comment: I *think* you need to sand down to bare wood on the affected spots

Comment: Agree, @MartinBonner. The sap should be cleaned/sanded off and then a couple coats of Bull's Eye is an excellent choice.